# Is there any way to pass body with parameters in GET request, by using reactjs, fetch or axios or any other way

Tags: reactjs

fetch(".../search", {
      // Adding method type
      method: "GET",

```
  // Adding body or contents to send
  data: JSON.stringify(data),

  // Adding headers to the request
  headers: headers
})
  .then(function(response) {
    callback(response);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    callback(err);
  });
```